# Cloudinary Search API using multiple tags

Tags: cloudinary

I am using the Search API (.net) and need to search using multiple tags.
Example:

```
tags: shoe and women and red
```

This should return all shoes for women that are red. Using a single tag *.Expression("tags=shoe")* works but not multiple tags.

Failed Code:

```
SearchResult result = cloudinary.Search()
.Expression("tags=shoe women red")
.Execute();
```

Failed Code:

```
SearchResult result = cloudinary.Search()
.Expression("tags=shoe,women,red")
.Execute();
```

Both examples do not work with multiple tags.

How do I search using the Search API with multiple tags?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the following:

```
SearchResult result = cloudinary.Search()
    .Expression("tags=shoe AND women AND red")
    .WithField("tags")
    .Execute();
```

Using the **AND** between each tag worked.

I have asked Cloudinary Support to update the docs:
https://cloudinary.com/documentation/search_api#expression_fields